# Listview doesn't refresh the item view correctly

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm  developing an app with xamarin forms and the MVVM pattern. I have a page with a listview that has three buttons but all the time with only 2 visibles and change the visibility of two of them when I press a button. The problem is that for the first ten items it works like supposed to be, press the button and dissapear and appear the other, but after the 10th item when I press the button it dissapear but the other doesn't appear until I scrool the list view to a position where the item is out of the screen. When the item is out of the screen and come back to be on the screen, the button appear. The visibility of the buttons is controlled changing a boolean property that is binded to the IsVisible property of the button and one of them with a converter to negate the value of the property. This is a [repository](https://jlzapata.visualstudio.com/ListViewBug/_git/ListViewBug) that you can clone and see the code and test, maybe is something with my Visual Studio.

Initially, I thought it could be for a race condition and made the method that change the variable synchronous but it doesn't work.

This is my list view

```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                          HasUnevenRows="True"
                          SeparatorVisibility="None"
                          IsRefreshing="False">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Button Text="One" 
                                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                                TextColor="Green"                                                     
                                                BackgroundColor="White"
                                                BorderColor="Green"
                                                BorderWidth="1"
                                                WidthRequest="150" />
                                        <Button Text="Two"
                                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                                BackgroundColor="Green"
                                                TextColor="White"
                                                Command="{Binding TestCommand}"
                                                WidthRequest="150"
                                                IsVisible="{Binding TestVariable, Converter={StaticResource negate}}" />
                                        <Button Text="Three"
                                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                                BackgroundColor="Red"
                                                Command="{Binding TestCommand}"
                                                TextColor="White"
                                                WidthRequest="150"
                                                IsVisible="{Binding TestVariable}" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

The viewmodel

```
 public class ListViewTestModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private List<ListItemTestModel> items;
        public List<ListItemTestModel> Items
        {
            get => items;
            set
            {
                SetValue(ref items, value);
            }
        }


        public ListViewTestModel()
        {
            List<ListItemTestModel> itemList = new List<ListItemTestModel>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
            {
                itemList.Add(new ListItemTestModel { Name = "Test" });
            }

            Items = itemList;
        }
    }
```

And another view model that is binded to each item in the listView

```
public class ListItemTestModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private bool testVariable;
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool TestVariable
        {
            get
            {
                return testVariable;
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ref testVariable, value);
            }
        }

        public Command TestCommand { get; set; }

        public ListItemTestModel()
        {
            TestCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
                TestMethod();
            });
        }

        public void TestMethod()
        {
            TestVariable = !TestVariable;
        }
    }
```

the BaseViewModel

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        protected void SetValue<T>(ref T backingField, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingField, value))
            {
                return;
            }

            backingField = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
```

And the codebehind of the page

```
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ListViewTestModel ViewModel { get; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            ViewModel = new ListViewTestModel();
            BindingContext = ViewModel;
             InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code on github does not show any items in your listview when the App is started. Somehow the view/viewmodel binding seems to be broken

Comment: It works for me, but I changed the initialization order in main page. Try again and tell me!

Comment: I have already noticed this issue, fixed it as you proposed and gave it another shot but I still could not get the listview items to display. Then I moved the ViewModel Binding to xaml since this is a bit more fool proof in my opinion (setting the Contentpage.BindingContext property) but this did not work either

Comment: I even created a new solution and copied the files over since I suspected there was some configuration issue but this also did not resolve the issue. I am baffled. This should work

Comment: Update your work enviroment and test. Maybe you have a problem with your installation.

Comment: I tested in iOS and it works.

Comment: @julian, I test your code, If I click the second Button in Stacklayout, some buttons change color red, some buttons disappear?

Comment: Yes @CherryBu, that is the problem. The button red should appear always but I note that the items that are off the screen at the moment when the page is initialized doesn't appear.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest listview Caching Strategy may case this issue, the default value is RetainElement for ListView, so using **CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"** in ListView.

About listview Caching Strategy, you can take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance#caching-strategy

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely go to `ObservableCollection` type for your items thus you'll be able to observe and display any changes

```
   private ObservableCollection<ListItemTestModel> items;
        public ObservableCollection<ListItemTestModel> Items
        {
            get => items;
            set => SetValue(ref items, value);

        }
```

And you should set your BindingContext **AFTER** the InitializeComponent() method or property changed will be propagate before your view is initialized.

```
public MainPage()
    {      
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new ListViewTestModel();;
    }



public ListViewTestModel()
        {
            List<ListItemTestModel> itemList = new List<ListItemTestModel>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
            {
                itemList.Add(new ListItemTestModel { Name = "Test" });
            }

            Items = new ObservableCollection<ListItemTestModel>(itemList);
        }
```